# How can I change the default styles for Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

In Google Docs, how can I change the built-in paragraph styles for a document? For example, the font size, font family, line and paragraph spacing, etc.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This can be done in new Google Docs (Drive) as well.

1. Do the necessary styling in a part of the document.
2. Place your mouse pointer over this location.
3. Click on the style selector and select the style you want to change the defaults of.
4. Click on update option to change the defaults.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As @Gokul N K said, you update the normal styles to become the default styles for *that* document. However, if you would like to change the default styles for every new document:

1. Update the styles that you want for every new document on a new document.
2. Click on the styles button > options > Save as my default styles
   [image: Edit default styles]

Or go to Format > Paragraph Styles > Options > Save as my default styles
[image: Edit default styles]
 3. Open a new document and see the styles have changed!

Source: "Set and change a default style" from support.google.com/docs/answer/116338