# How do I add new styles to Google docs?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

Google docs has a nice set of styles such as "Normal text" and "Heading 1".

[image: Style dropdown in Google Docs: "Normal text", "Title"/"Subtitle", "Heading"s]

How do I add my own? I want to add a style called "code" for text that is programming code.

Comment: I know the answer but I cannot add it because I don't have enough reputation. Basically you can utilize the Google Apps Scripts, here is what I did: http://pastebin.com/4pNBJ9pC. In order to enable it you need to create a new script: `Tools` >> `Script Manager` >> `New` and paste the code there. Then you will have to authorize the script and reload the document so that the menu appears on in the menu bar. Then select a patch of text and pick `Extras` >> `Apply code style`

Comment: I know my answer but my 101 reputation is, apparently, not enough.  As of 3/14', once you update the existing headers via "Update Heading X to match", GDocs will add an additional Heading Y. So, it starts with just Heading 1,2,3, but once you update Heading 3, GDocs will introduce Heading 4.  Once you update Heading 4, GDocs will introduce Heading 5, etc.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov answer helped me with this one. I've updated and fixed some issues with it here https://github.com/cr8ivecodesmith/google_docs_scripts/blob/master/apply_code_style.js

Comment: @ChrisMoschini I tried out that extension, but it doesn't allow me to use many of the fonts, including monospaced fonts, which is precisely what i need

Comment: I've learned to work backwards: format a load of empty newlines at the end of the document in your preferred code style and so you always write in monospace first. Then press alt-cmd-0 to format the NON-CODE paragraphs back to Normal. My ratio of text to code is probably equal anyway.

Comment: I ended up using this plugin: Code Blocks by  Alex Forsythe.

Comment: I wonder if a useful workaround might be to do editing of the document in OpenOffice, where you can style as needed, then upload into Google Docs from there ... I know it's a pain, but if the document is mainly in Google Docs for ease of portability (like some are for me), it might be helpful, since no solution currently offers what is actually desired ...

Comment: @ChrisMoschini I wish Paragraph Style+ extension works!

Comment: @AaronWallentine Most people already edit styles elsewhere I guess. What we need is a way in Gdoc. I understand why it doesn't exist. As Paragraph Style+ made that, it is possible.

Comment: @KristófDombi Code Blocks plugin adds new styles?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Right now it's not possible to add more styles or rename the existed ones, but you can modify them to match your needs.

For example you could style your code as you wish and then by selecting one of the headers and choosing the `Update Heading # to match selection`, that particular style could become your new *"Code"* style.

Then select something else and apply that heading and you're done.

[image: Styles in google docs]

Comment: downside is this will include "code" in my TOC. :/

I found that using Subtitle style for code prevents it from showing in TOC.

Comment: +1 @digger69 for that tip. Using “Subtitle” for code is the single best tip I've ever gotten from this StackExchange. Great for having line-height 1.15 throughout the document, but 1.0 for code! :D

Comment: As I also mentioned in digger69's answer, another downside is that this does not allow for inline styles; it has to be on its own line. Of course, short code, or more likely, code-related terms (such as tag, function or variable names) often want to live inline within a paragraph of text.

Comment: is it true that it has to be "block" meaning the whole line or paragraph must be that same style --  it cannot be a line with `code` mixed with normal text like this: the `window` object

Comment: Better illustration here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/37776/10579

Comment: Personally, to insert example code, I use a drawing with a text box.  Insert > Drawing, add a text box, paste the code, format as desired, click Save & Close.

Comment: As of 9/5/2018, this is no longer the correct answer. You can now select "Options" > "Save as My Default Styles". Unfortunately I don't have the rep on this SE to post the current answer.

Comment: This only seems to work for the full line, not very useful for most cases. 
 @BenjaminS I couldn't find out how to get that to work.

Comment: Kludgey. Uses something not designed for the purpose.

Comment: A catch to using any Heading level or Subtitle is that it tries to avoid a block spanning pages (probably as a side effect of trying to keep headings with their following paragraph).As best I can tell, it's not configurable. (It will only do this once per block, so at least code blocks longer than one page don't go completely haywire.)

Comment: This is just not a solution. Plain and simple. Having code show up in your table of contents should have been the first clue.

Answer (score 74):

As Lipis poins out, you still cannot create your own styles. So, you are left to repurpose an existing one. The downside to using Heading is this will result in "code" in my Table of Contents (TOC). :/ I found that using Title and Subtitle styles for code prevents those styles from showing in TOC.

Comment: The main downside of this approach is that while you can use ⌘+Alt+6 to use this layout if you override 6'th heading, there is no matching keyboard shortcut for the Subtitle style.

Comment: The other note is that this doesn't seem to work inline, has to be on its own line (true of all styles I imagine)

Comment: If you also "Remove the space after paragraph" in "Line spacing" menu button you don't need to worry about paragraphs and using Shift + Enter as opposed to Enter anymore.

Answer (score 62):

A lot of the solutions don't work inline. This is a cleaned-up solution offered by @AlekseyBykov using Google App Scripts to add a custom menu action:

1. Create a new script (`Tools > Script Editor`)
2. Copy the following code into the editor:

```
// Add new menu item
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Styles')
  .addItem('Format Code', 'formatCode')
  .addToUi();
}

// Define code styling
var style = {};
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = DocumentApp.FontFamily.CONSOLAS;
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 10;
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = "#DDDDDD";
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = "#333333";
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;

// Apply code formatting
function formatCode() {
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];

      // Only modify elements that can be edited as text; skip images and other non-text elements.
      if (element.getElement().editAsText) {
        var text = element.getElement().editAsText();

        // Style the selected part of the element, or the full element if it's completely selected.
        if (element.isPartial()) {
          text.setAttributes(element.getStartOffset(), element.getEndOffsetInclusive(), style);
        } else {
          text.setAttributes(style);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. Assign a trigger to run the `onOpen` function "On open" (`Edit > Current Project's Triggers`)
4. After authorizing the script, reload the original document
5. Use the new menu item to format selected text (`Styles > Format Code`)

Comment: Excellent and worked perfectly.

For a more 'Slack' backtick style:


style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = "#FFEEEE";
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = "#880000";

Comment: excellent stuff. I didn't like that the background was missing between words, so I modified it to put the content in a table cell with a solid background: https://gist.github.com/fatso83/ffb7871c537e04d9ce95f66fccc30495

Comment: super nice script, thanks! I could now extend it to support more styles

Comment: The `FontFamily` [enum has been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/font-family). Instead of `FontFamily.FONT_NAME`, just use the (case sensitive) label found in the font menu, such as `style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = "Roboto Mono"` (or "Source Code Pro" or "Courier New" as explained in the [setFontFamily docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setfontfamilyfontfamilyname)).

Comment: One limitation is that you can't easily change the style of all existing "code" strings in your text (eg you decide that all inline code should be 9-pt intsead of 10). You would need an "old style" style in the script, and a function that search all the text for style that matches the old code style, finds the end, and changes to new style... That being said, this is the only practical approach because 80% of time it's inline text you need to style.

Comment: Great solution! I've figured out you can leave code formatting mode using the hotkeys for, e.g., normal text (CTRL + ALT + 0). But is there a way to get hotkeys to enable this? The only trigger option I have for this script is "OnOpen".  Even better, could we do in-line markdown characters to trigger it? (e.g. backticks)

Comment: Brilliant solution!  Now can you add a button to the menu?

Comment: Works great. I second the desire for hotkeys with @BenB

Comment: this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: One improvement I added since it bugged me that it fails when I select 'over' the end of a paragraph: `let start = element.getStartOffset() > -1 ? element.getStartOffset() : 0;
let end = element.getEndOffsetInclusive() > -1 ? element.getEndOffsetInclusive() : text.getText().length - 1; 
text.setAttributes(start, end, style);` 
instead of the line `text.setAttributes(element.getStartOffset(), element.getEndOffsetInclusive(), style);`

Comment: Excellent! Now it seems to only apply to one document. How do you apply it to all your current and future documents?

Comment: @BenB there's currently no way to run App Script via hotkeys; see this question for background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731589/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-app-script-functions

Comment: I've modified this a little to work with multiple styles. Can't post an answer yet, so here's a link: [custom-styles.js](https://gist.github.com/akinuri/c5b2d67744d6e4f5ea56a2f55a512a73)

Answer (score 16):

The gratis Google Docs extension [Paragraph Styles+](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/paragraph-styles%20/pbfegackndhdneogcnlhhihgkphkggdh) allows to create custom paragraph styles (plus decimal system outline numbering for headings and a table of contents with page numbering).

I just tested it, and here's my first impression:

- Good start. For small-ish documents, it should be good to use :-)
- However it runs quite slow, even though recent versions improved on the performance already.
- The UI does not integrate with the Google Docs style UI. Probably not possible otherwise in the Google Docs API.
- The original Google Docs style feature does not know about custom styles, considering all text with custom styles as having the "Normal text" format. You can use both in parallel, but note that the "Clear formatting" button (looks like "**T<sub>x</sub>**") will remove custom style formatting from selected text.
- It seems to store your character styles on an external web service, means you have to entrust them access to your documents the way you entrust them to Google now …

*Source:* Acknowledging the [comment by Chris Moschini](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24249/how-do-i-add-new-styles-to-google-docs#comment68097_24249) above, who mentioned it first.

Comment: Are there any [data security risks](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2608717/web-browsers/many-chrome-browser-extensions-do-sneaky-things.html) involved with installing this kind of docs extension, or has the code been verified by Google to be non-malicious?

Comment: [These permissions](http://i.imgur.com/jvgWjP7.png) appear to enable, for example, your documents to be sent to or shared with others without further notice. That certainly scares me.

Comment: It looks like Google now longer allows this extension to be installed.

Answer (score 16):

The workaround I've come to rely on is the **Copy/Paste Format** feature shortcut. As the format "clipboard" is separate from the text clipboard, it is preserved for as long as you have the document open.

To use:

- find a section you have formatted as "code", e.g. Consolas 9pt.
- Use `option + command + c` or `Ctrl + Alt + c` or use the Paint Format icon
- Wherever you need "code" select it and press `option + command + v` or `Ctrl + Alt + v`

If you only need one extra style, I find this very little extra work, with no drawbacks, compared to other options. The only work is to initially copy the style to the buffer when opening a new document.

---

The other technique I use (as I commented on the question) is to invert the problem: **always type in "code" format** at the end of the document then reset any *non-code* to normal using `command + option + 0".

When I'm writing technical documents, if 50% of the text is code, then this is also no extra work.

The only tip here is to format the very last linefeed character in the document as "code", else it keeps revering to normal. This is done by arrowing down to the end, then hold shift and right-arrow - it will select *one more* sneaky character. Then format that as code. Now the end of the document will always be in code by default.

Comment: This does not provide any of the benefits of defining styles. The main purpose of styles is that you don’t have to update every occurrence of styled text when you modify the style.

Answer (score 10):

Until recently, it was possible to edit the CSS (stylesheet) and HTML source of a document. It took some work, but if you knew HTML and CSS you could add a CSS class to your doc, and then edit the HTML to use it, e.g. in the HTML

```
<span class='booktitle'>Infinite Jest</span>
```

and in the CSS

```
.booktitle { font-style:italic; }
```

Google has more or less phased out this capability with their new format, forcing old docs to the new format. But, I've heard there are ways to keep docs in the old format, so there may be some hope.

Comment: I would love more info about how to do this.

Comment: Doesnt work, google now strips all css except inlines

Comment: The [script posted above](https://github.com/cr8ivecodesmith/google_docs_scripts) is almost the same as this feature.  After installing, you can simply edit the `style` object as needed.  It's javascript, so slightly different than CSS, but almost identical.  Note: it does not make any external calls, send or load data from elsewhere.