# Define and reuse paragraph/character styles?

Tags: google-slides

Is there a way to define reusable paragraph/character styles in Google Slides (Presentations)?

I only found some old questions, like this https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/irdO-txGV3Y .
This question is from 2015, so I think it is valid to ask again at this point...

Please note, my question is specifically about Slides app, not Google Docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add new styles to Google docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24249/how-do-i-add-new-styles-to-google-docs)

Comment: Please note, my question is specifically about Slides app, not Google Docs

Comment: Could you post a screenshot then of what your trying to achieve? Because so far it seems that the official response from Google (the link you've posted) holds true and the only editable things you can do are https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1663349?hl=en&ref_topic=1361461