# Define special inline styles in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, text-formatting

I am using Google Docs to write some documents. At certain points, I have to write inline some formulas I would like to have a different font, letter size and color. 
I like to experiment with different fonts and styles, but I find it really bothersome to go line by line changing them.

Is there a way I can instruct Google Docs to link the styles of those formulas, so that when I change one all of them change?

Comment: Related question with a few more votes: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24249/how-do-i-add-new-styles-to-google-docs/45653

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, custom **named** styles (like "Normal text" etc.) are not yet supported and nobody is aware of any plans to implement them.

However, *implicit*, "by example" styles exist and can be used with decent efficiency via "Copy format", "Paste format", "Paint format" and "Select all matching text" functions.

The usage is roughly like this:

1. In order to **create** an implicit style, select an unmarked text passage and tune its properties. Adjust font style, weight, size, color etc.
2. In order to **use** an implicit style, step on marked up text, and do a "Copy format" by pressing Alt+Ctrl+C. Then, select an unmarked text passage and do a "Paste format" by pressing Alt+Ctrl+V.
3. Alternatively you can use the "Paint format" icon on the toolbar.
4. In order to **adjust** an existing implicit style, right-click on a styled text passage and click "Select all matching text" in the pull-down menu. Then adjust font style, weight, size, color etc.

WARNING! 99% of Earth population are yet unaware of this due to Google's stup^H^H^H^Hinformation policy. The majority of us earthlings still believe that Google Docs hasn't got text styles and thus sucks.

Cheers!

Comment: For those on a Mac, I confirmed this works as Alex describes with CMD+OPTION+C and +V.  (⌘+⌥+C)

Comment: This is such a great help!!

Comment: These do not seem to be styles, though - it seems to be an ability to copy-paste direct formatting. `Clear formatting` would reset all direct formatting to actual styles - and it would remove direct formatting no matter how it appeared there (like through copying of the formatting). Contrast this with character styles in OpenOffice/LibreOffice.

Answer (score -1):

Make these a Heading (under Format > Paragraph styles) then, when happy with one instance, select `Update 'Heading n' to match`.

Comment: When I use a paragraph style, the whole paragraph changes. I want to change only some formulas which are *inline*