# Is it possible to Export Google Doc Default Styles?

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

I have customized my default styles to my liking.  Got my fonts set, sizes, etc.  **I'd like to export them so I can give it to other people in my company -or- use it for a different google account of mine.**

As of December 2013, there doesn't appear to be anyway to do this but wanted to see if anyone had a creative solution.

Note: I'm not asking how to set the default styles.  I've done this already.  See: [How can I change the default styles for Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6412/how-can-i-change-the-default-styles-for-google-docs)

Answer (score 2):

You can make an empty document with the account that has been customised. Share this document to your other Google account and in that other account go to `Format - Paragraph styles - Options - Save as my default style`. Now your other account should have the same customised styles as default.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised that in 2020 there isn't a way to export and import styles.

The other answer is clever, but I didn't want to set the document styles as my default style because it is just one of many styles I am using on my Google account.

My solution was to open the source document (the one with the styles I wanted to export) and format an example of every style.

E.g.

```
Title
Subtitle
Heading One
Heading Two
Heading Three
Heading Four
Heading Five
Heading Six
Normal Text
```

I then copied and pasted this into my destination document (to update) and then highlighted each style and then choose the option to Update "Heading 1" to match for each.

When you're done, use the option to "Clear formatting" which will change all the formatting in the document to use the updated styles.

A bit tedious, and not really a suitable answer to the original question. But perhaps my answer will help someone else.