# How to apply a Google Docs template styles to an existing doc

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-template

I have a Google Document that was created using default styles. Our company has since created some Google Docs templates to use for styling. I'd like to apply the template's styling to this existing document, which is quite long, without having to copy/paste each heading and body text element into a new document. Is there a way to do this?

I found [this Google documentation on how to create a new document from a template](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/148833), but I couldn't find anything about how to apply template styling to a pre-existing document.

Comment: I that the question wording should be more specific as what you really need is to import the styles from one document to another.

Comment: @Rubén I updated the subject. Feel free to further edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Export Google Doc Default Styles?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52733/is-it-possible-to-export-google-doc-default-styles)

Comment: @Rubén not a duplicate since my question is about converting an existing document, which is not covered in that linked question.

Answer (score 11):

It's sort of a hassle, but copy paste a block of text with a title, subtitle, header 1,2,3,4, etc into your old doc, then one by one, select a bit of the text with the correct style, and "update Title to match", "update Header 1 to match"...

And finally, select all > Format > Paragraph Styles > Options > Use my default styles.

Comment: Definitely a hassle. I hope there is an easier way.

Answer (score 7):

Just worked out that at the bottom of the styles menu you can save current styles as your default. Makes it a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

Open the template document, delete everything, copy&paste your document there, select all, press C-\ to remove styling, copy&paste back to your original document.

Note that the C-\ step is not equivalent to copy&paste-wo-formatting, since the latter will remove "logical" formatting too (like headings or titles).